# Adding text below my li items

Tags: html, css, web

I am currently working on some sort of progress tracker in one of my projects right now. I have the following working already:

```css
li {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: gray;
  margin: 0 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

li::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: .9em;
  left: -4em;
  width: 4em;
  height: .2em;
  background: lightgray;
  z-index: -1;
}


li:first-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  background: red;
}

.active ~ li {
  background: lightgray;
}

.active ~ li::before {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>&#10004;</li>
  <li>&#10004;</li>
  <li>&#10004;</li>
  <li class="active">4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
</ul>
```

Now I wanted to add a span below each li to label each step. I tried adding a styled;span but when I add a longer text it destroys my layout.

Comment: What have you already tried? Please provide a [minimal and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I guess you should use `text-overflow: ellipsis`. but why your texts in `span` in `li` may be longer than 2 chars? How many steps you have?

Comment: Also for centering the `span`s inside `li` please use `flex box`, it's awesome and works well.

Comment: try with ::after CSS and let me know whether this is what you want `li::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1.9em;
    left: -4em;
    z-index: -1;
    content: 'TEXT';
    color: #000;
}`

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this. This code pulls text from `data-step` attribute and shows using pseudo classes

[image]

```css
li {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: gray;
  margin: 0 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

li::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: .9em;
  left: -4em;
  width: 4em;
  height: .2em;
  background: lightgray;
  z-index: -1;
}


li:first-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  background: red;
}

.active ~ li {
  background: lightgray;
}

.active ~ li::before {
  background: lightgray;
}
li > span { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 2em; 
  left: 0; 
  line-height: 110%;
  color: #000; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-step="step 1">&#10004;</li>
  <li data-step="step 2">&#10004;</li>
  <li data-step="step 3">&#10004;</li>
  <li data-step="step 4" class="active">4</li>
  <li data-step="step 5">5</li>
  <li data-step="step 6">6</li>
  <li data-step="step 7">7<span>some text</span></li>
</ul>
```

> Now I wanted to add a span below each li to label each step. I tried
>   adding a styled;span but when I add a longer text it destroys my
>   layout.

Just add span like this

```
<li>7<span>some text</span></li>
```

and change styles like this

```
li > span { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 2em; 
  left: 0; 
  line-height: 110%;
  content: attr(data-step); 
  color: #000; }
```

```css
li {
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  background: gray;
  margin: 0 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}

li::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: .9em;
  left: -4em;
  width: 4em;
  height: .2em;
  background: lightgray;
  z-index: -1;
}


li:first-child::before {
  display: none;
}

.active {
  background: red;
}

.active ~ li {
  background: lightgray;
}

.active ~ li::before {
  background: lightgray;
}
li > span { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 2em; 
  left: 0; 
  line-height: 110%;
  color: #000; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>&#10004; <span>step 1</span></li>
  <li>&#10004;<span>step 2</span></li>
  <li>&#10004;<span>step 3</span></li>
  <li class="active">4<span>step 4</span></li>
  <li>5<span>step 5</span></li>
  <li>6<span>step 6</span></li>
  <li>7<span>some text</span></li>
</ul>
```